# Network routing depending URL Alias

Tags: networking, routes, dns, gateway, vhosts

I have 2 websites :

- **www.AAAAAAAA.com**
- **www.AAAAAAAA.com/BBBBB**

Each one reply on a different IP

- **www.AAAAAAAA.com** >> 192.168.0.111
- **www.AAAAAAAA.com/BBBBB**  >> 192.168.0.222

How can I configure my local DNS / Hosts file / gateway / vhosts to make the difference between each site and automaticaly solve www.AAAAAAAA.com with the good IP ? (depending if there is /BBBBB in the URL)

Answer (score 1):

I know this one.

Which web server are you using? Apache has a function where you can store, similar to virtual hosts but using a /BBBBB instead I have been trying to find out how to do this as well.

The only way I know of doing this is to run both sites off the same web server using Vhosts.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/
or
IIS Bindings for the site.

Using different folders for each would be able to use.

Set these CNAME records in your hosted Domain Name Server and then should be able to access from both.

BBBBB.AAAAAA.com

www.AAAAAA.com

Comment: To full go down to what the OP wanted would use [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to change it but needs to be enabled on the webhost for it to work so if AAA.com/BBB proxy to IP